# Augmented Reality using SceneKit and OpenCV. [Extrinsic Matrix]

Tags: ios, opencv, matrix, opengl-es, scenekit

I have been trying to get an AR app working with `SceneKit` and `OpenCV` for a while now. I have something working, but it is not good enough.

It is a slightly complex pipeline, so I will describe it in parts and maybe you could tell me whether I am making wrong assumptions/logical mistakes.

First I obtain the `Intrinsic Matrix` by running the standard `opencv` checkerboard algorithm for camera calibration.

Then I use the

```
     intrinsic matrix,
     3D model of the marker,
     points in the image corresponding to the marker
```

in `opencv`'s `solvePnP` (+ `rodrigues`) to get the `extrinsic matrix`. Standard Stuff.

Now I need to convert this `extrinsic matrix` from `OpenCv`'s `Coordinate System` to the `SceneKit` `Coordinate System`.

This conversion is done as follows :

Since `OpenCV` has a left handed coordinate system:

- `+Z` away from the camera
- `+X` to the right
- `+Y` down

and `SceneKit` has a right handed coordinate system:

- `+Z` into the camera
- `+X` to the right
- and `+Y` up

I invert the `Y` and `Z` axis with this code:

```
    // convert from left hand coor in opencv to right handed coor in opengl and scenekit

    cv::Mat cvToGl = cv::Mat::zeros(4, 4, CV_32F);
    cvToGl.at<float>(0, 0) = 1.0f;
    cvToGl.at<float>(1, 1) = -1.0f; // Invert the y axis.
    cvToGl.at<float>(2, 2) = -1.0f; // invert the z axis
    cvToGl.at<float>(3, 3) = 1.0f;

    extrinMatrix = cvToGl * extrinMatrix;
```

**Question 1:** Are these assumptions right, and is the matrix multiplication right ?

To further complicate matters `OpenCV` has a column order matrix representation, while `SceneKit` has a row order matrix (the matrix is the homogenous matrix representing the rotation and translation matrix and vector respectively).

```
    In OpenCV/GL :

    ROT | TRAN
    0   |   1

    In Scene Kit

    ROT  |   0
    TRAN |   1
```

So to do this conversion as follows :

```
-(SCNMatrix4) transformToSceneKit:(cv::Mat&) RightHandtransform
{

    SCNMatrix4 mat = SCNMatrix4Identity; 

    // RightHandtransform is column major
    // Scene Kit is row major.
    RightHandtransform = RightHandtransform.t(); // Take the transpose

    // Copy the rotation rows
    // Copy the first row.
    mat.m11 = RightHandtransform.at<float>(0,0);
    mat.m12 = RightHandtransform.at<float>(0,1);
    mat.m13 = RightHandtransform.at<float>(0,2);
    mat.m14 = RightHandtransform.at<float>(0,3);

    mat.m21 = RightHandtransform.at<float>(1,0);
    mat.m22 = RightHandtransform.at<float>(1,1);
    mat.m23 = RightHandtransform.at<float>(1,2);
    mat.m24 = RightHandtransform.at<float>(1,3);

    mat.m31 = RightHandtransform.at<float>(2,0);
    mat.m32 = RightHandtransform.at<float>(2,1);
    mat.m33 = RightHandtransform.at<float>(2,2);
    mat.m34 = RightHandtransform.at<float>(2,3);

    //Copy the translation row. Which is the bottom row in SceneKIT
    mat.m41 = RightHandtransform.at<float>(3,0);
    mat.m42 = RightHandtransform.at<float>(3,1);
    mat.m43 = RightHandtransform.at<float>(3,2);
    mat.m44 = RightHandtransform.at<float>(3,3);

    return mat;
}
```

**Question 2:** Is this conversion right, and the transpose I do should convert from `column major` ordering to `row major` ordering ?

So now we have the extrinsic matrix from `opencv` in `scene kit`. I am not absolutely sure about this, as I found conflicting information about this, but the extrinsic matrix obtained from `solvePnP`, describes the rotation and translation of the model in the camera coordinate system.

**Question 3:** Is that right?

So now the only thing that I have to do is to set the transform property of the `SCNNode` and the model should show up in the right location in the `SCNCamera` coordinate system. But it is a bit buggy.

I also have code for doing the perspective projection from the camera coor to clip space (`NDC`). Due to the length, I will write it up as different question.

**Question 4:** Are the assumptions that I am making sound?

I don't have a lot of experience with graphics, so if I am doing something very stupid please alert me to it. Thank you.

**Sidenote:**

I am not interested in using a 3D party software.

Comment: @Sneak This part has 3 questions in it. I think breaking into smaller questions will not give enough context.

Comment: I'm glad you edited your question. I have further edited it to make it more clear. GL.

Comment: @Sneak Thanks a lot for your corrections.

Comment: @nnrales: Have you find out how to properly create the projection and perspective matrixes to work out with Open CV?

Comment: Both OpenCV and SceneKit have right-handed coordinate systems. They’re just oriented differently with respect to the camera.

Comment: Hi @nnrale, I am looking into how to get those in/extrinsic matrix from with ARKit. Could you help me out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62867707/swift-access-to-arkit-camera-parameters-and-save-them